# how to concatenate multiple strings to make up an x:Name in xamarin UWP?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

Is it  possible to concatenate a few strings to make up an x:Name?  For example, can I do something like this?

```
  <Label Grid.Column="1" 
        x:Name="CheckoutStatus_{0}, {Binding Path=DriveItem.Name}"
        Text="{Binding Path=DriveItem.Publication.Level,Converter={StaticResource IconValueConverter}}" 
        FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" 
        FontSize="Small"
        PropertyChanged="CheckoutStatusChanged"/>
```

This way in the event handler, I can do something like this (pseudocode):

```
    private void CheckoutStatusChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var selectedLabel = (Label)sender; 
        if the label name contains string "CheckoutStatatus"
                extract the filename from the current label
                do some other stuff. 
    }
```

How do I grab the value in the x:Name and parse the filename out?
If I can just get the filename, I think I can figure out how to parse.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to concatenate a few strings to make up an x:Name?

Short answer: No.

The `x:Name` XAML *attribute* cannot be set dynamically.

In WPF, where the `Label` control resides, there is a `Name` *dependency property* that you can bind to though:

```
<Label Name="{Binding SomeProperty}" />
```

In UWP, you will have to use another property such as for example `Tag` or a custom attached property.